# Python Classes: Appending a list & Incorporating a Method

Tags: python, class, chess

I just started learning about Python classes today and I had a quick question. I'm pretty amazed how much more succinct it has made my code, but I'm trying to figure out if the following is possible for a chess problem I'm working on.

**(1)** **Can I append a list somehow from within a class method?** I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to accumulate the pieces in a list each time *capture* is called.

**(2)** **How can I call a method from within the class to be used in another method?** I would like to be able to check if a move is valid before even proceeding if the piece should try to capture another or move.

```
class Piece(Board):

def __init__(self, piece, r, c):
    self.piece = piece
    self.r = r
    self.c = c
```

#### This is the function I would like to incorporate into the functions below to avoid the redundancy (Question 2)

```
def valid_move(self,r,c,r_offset,c_offset):
    #r, c are integers for the coordinates on the board
    #r_offset,c_offset are the cells the piece might move to
    self.tgt_r, self.tgt_c = r+r_offset, c+c_offset

    if self.tgt_r <= 7 or self.tgt_c >= 0:
            return True
    return False
```

#### These functions are the same for now. I'm trying to see how I can use the capture function to accumulate a list of pieces once they're taken. (Question 1)

```
def capture(self,r,c, r_offset, c_offset): 

    piece = self.piece
    self.tgt_r, self.tgt_c = r+r_offset, c+c_offset 

    if self.tgt_r > 7 or self.tgt_c < 0:
            return None             
    else:
        nb = Board(curr).copy_board() #this board is just 8x8 np.array
        nb[self.tgt_r,self.tgt_c], nb[r,c] = piece,'-'  
    return nb

def move(self,r,c, r_offset, c_offset):

    piece = self.piece
    self.tgt_r, self.tgt_c = r+r_offset, c+c_offset 

    if self.tgt_r > 7 or self.tgt_c < 0:
        return None
    else:
        nb = Board(curr).copy_board()
        nb[self.tgt_r,self.tgt_c], nb[r,c] = piece,'-'  
    return nb
```

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Can I append a list somehow from within a class method?**

create a `list` -`piecesList` in your class for storing the pieces:

```
class Piece(Board):
    def __init__(self, piece, r, c):
        self.piece = piece
        self.r = r
        self.c = c
        self.piecesList = [] #or init using some argument if you want to use some list from outside of the class
```

and whenever your `capture` method is called, simply append the piece in the `piecesList` :

```
def capture(self,r,c, r_offset, c_offset): 
    self.piecesList.append(self.piece)
    piece = self.piece
```

**2.  How can I call a method from within the class to be used in another method?**

you can simply call it using `self.method(arg1, arg2...)` :

```
def capture(self,r,c, r_offset, c_offset): 

    piece = self.piece

    if self.valid_move(r,c,r_offset,c_offset) == False:
            return None             
    else:
        nb = Board(curr).copy_board() #this board is just 8x8 np.array
        nb[self.tgt_r,self.tgt_c], nb[r,c] = piece,'-'  
    return nb
```

Comment: Awesome - I'm addicted to these now...really powerful! Thanks!